# How to compile programs with libwebsockets Library?

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I use libwebsockets for a project . I installed it using Packet Manger on debian jessie .
It works well , but that packet is old , so I cloned the latest stable version from github . Now when I try to compile programs , i get error message

> undefined reference to `libwebsocket_create_context,
>  undefined reference to 'libwebsocket_create_context'

etc...
I compiled with the command :

```
gcc test.c -o test -lwebsockets
```

Comment: Use `-Lpath/to/your/compiled/websockets/library`

Comment: Are you sure there's a libwebsocket_create_context that you should call ? The documentation only mentions a  lws_create_context() function.

Comment: Yes you are right , the Syantax has changed , but even after I changed it does not work . What do you mean with the path . Can you show an example , I do not know   which path I chould  take

Comment: @user3011195 Did you find the solution? I am facing same issue.